# Monad Transformer and applicative Maybe

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, applicative, option-type

Inside a do block of a `ExceptT String IO ()`

I have a function that produces a ReaderT like so:

```
type UDCEnv = (AWS.Env, Bool)

uploadVersionFilesToCaches :: S3.BucketName
                               -> FilePath
                               -> [GitRepoNameAndVersion]
                               -> ReaderT UDCEnv IO ()
```

I just so happen to have a `Maybe FilePath` so I create my ReaderT like so:

```
let maybeReader ::  Maybe (ReaderT UDCEnv IO ()) =
    uploadVersionFilesToCaches s3BucketName <$> maybeFilePath <*> Just gitRepoNamesAndVersions
```

I can even run the ReaderT like so:

```
let maybeIO :: Maybe (IO ()) = 
    runReaderT <$> maybeReader <*> Just (env, shouldIgnoreLocalCache, verbose)
```

Everything works fine as long as I use `let` expressions. As soon as I drop the `let` in the expression above to actually try to have expression evaluated Applicative gets types as `ExceptT String IO FilePath` instead of `Maybe`

The parts I am omitting are marked by `...` :

```
f :: ... -> ExceptT String IO ()
f ... = do
   ... 
   runReaderT <$> maybeReader <*> Just (env, shouldIgnoreLocalCache, verbose) -- Error here
   undefined
```

Produces

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO ()’ with ‘()’
Expected type: ReaderT UDCEnv IO () -> UDCEnv -> ()
  Actual type: ReaderT UDCEnv IO () -> UDCEnv -> IO ()
In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘runReaderT’
In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
  ‘runReaderT
   <$>
     (uploadVersionFilesToCaches s3BucketName <$> maybeFilePath
      <*> Just gitRepoNamesAndVersions)’
/Users/blender/Code/Personal/Haskell/Rome-Public/src/Lib.hs: 82, 73

Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘ExceptT String IO’
    Expected type: ExceptT String IO FilePath
      Actual type: Maybe FilePath
    In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘maybeFilePath’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘uploadVersionFilesToCaches s3BucketName <$> maybeFilePath’
```

I think the first error is because I'm missing some `liftIO` somewhere.

However I have no idea what to do about the misunderstood Applicative.

I could case analysis on the Maybe of course instead of using Applicative but I would really prefer not to.

Comment: Judging from the error, you are missing `return`, not `liftIO`.

Comment: @arrowd could well be, but unfortunately that does not help with my applicative problem here. Maybe this is not the right approach to begin with?

Comment: Can you include the code where the `runReaderT ...` expression actually appears?  Most likely, it's being used in the do-block in a such a way that Haskell is trying to type it as `ExceptT String IO ()` instead of `Maybe (IO ())`.  This would ultimately explain both errors, as `Maybe` isn't `ExceptT String IO`, and `()` isn't `IO ()`.  It may be as simple as adding a standard Maybe-to-ExceptT interface.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr it just appears in the middle of a `do` block in a `ExceptT String IO ()` see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Oops, fixed a bug.

There seems to be a minor inconsistency in your question, because the do-block you provide contains a `runReaderT ...` expression that doesn't match the expression given in your error message.

However, ultimately the problem is this:  in a do-block of type `m a` for some monad `m`, each plain expression (and each right-hand side of an `x <- y` expression) has to have type `m b` for some `b`.  So, by using your `runReaderT ...` expression in a do-block of type `ExceptT String IO ()`, you're forcing Haskell to type-check it as `ExceptT String IO a` for some `a`.  However, it's a `Maybe (IO ())`, so that type-checking will fail.

You'd get a similar error if you tried:

```
foo :: ExceptT String IO ()
foo = do Just (putStrLn "won't work")   -- has type Maybe (IO ())
         undefined
```

You need to decide how to adapt the `runReaderT ...` expression to the surrounding do-block.  Two reasonable options are:

```
foo = do ...
         maybe (throwError "reader was Nothing!") liftIO
             $ runReaderT ...
         undefined
```

which will throw an `ExceptT`-style error if your `maybeReader` is `Nothing` or:

```
foo = do ...
         maybe (return ()) liftIO
             $ runReaderT ...
         undefined
```

which will do .. erm .. nothing in case of `Nothing`.

Comment: You are right, I was completely confused by the error message and all those `T`s . Generally I find it quite difficult to compose monad transformers, `maybe` (wink wink) I'm doing it wrong :)